# Continuity, derivatives of rational function

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm studying the continuity of a function and its derivatives checking if the function is continuous, differentiable and calculating some derivatives.
The function is

\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}& \text{if }\, (x,y)\neq 0\\
0& \text{if}\,\, (x,y)=0
\end{cases}

I'm asked to study the continuity in $(0,0)$.

**My work:**

I started checking the limit of the function for $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ and considered the trasformation in polar coordinates to get a easier limit:

$$\lim_{\rho\rightarrow 0} \frac{\rho^3\cos^2\theta \sin\theta}{\rho^2}=\lim_{\rho\rightarrow 0} \rho \cos^2\theta \sin\theta=0$$
So I got the continuity.

Then I've been asked to study the value of partial derivatives in $(0,0)$ and the directional derivatives in $(0,0)$ calculated on $y=x$.

I calculated the derivatives:

$f_x=\dfrac{2xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$,
this is not defined in $(0,0)$ so I considered the limit using polar coordinates again, and I got:
$$\lim_{\rho\rightarrow 0} \frac{2\rho^4 \cos\theta \sin^3\theta}{\rho^4}=2\cos\theta \sin^3\theta$$

Is it right? What can I say now about this limit?
The value of the derivatives in this point is supposed to be $0$ according to the solution given but I'm stuck in this point.

Besides  $f_y=\dfrac{x^4-x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$, from which I get to the same kind of problem (again the values is supposed to be $0$)

Finally the directional derivatives: I used the definition and got:

the vector of the direction is $(\sqrt2/2;\sqrt2/2)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ so

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\frac{\sqrt2}{2}t;\frac{\sqrt2}{2}t)-0}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2}t^2\cdot\frac{\sqrt2}{2}t}{\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{2}t^2}\cdot\frac{1}{t}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt2}{4}t^3}{t^2}\cdot\frac{1}{t}=\frac{\sqrt2}{4}$$

I have no idea how to finish the discussion of the two first derivatives and so how to check if the whole function is differentiable in the point $(0,0)$

Comment: Continuity is ok.

Comment: Why are you looking only at that direction derivative? Why ignore the others?

Comment: That's was what I'm asked to do. Check derivatives on the axes and on y=x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fly by Night says using the standard rules of differentiation "isn't allowed" for partial derivatives.  I'm not sure what exactly he/she means by this; however, in your case, you can still use your approach in calculating the values of $f_x$ and $f_y$, and I wanted to explain how.

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530577/if-a-derivative-of-a-continuous-function-has-a-limit-must-it-agree-with-that-li), you know the partial derivative $f_x(0,0)$ is equal to the limit of $f_x(0,h)$ as $h \to 0$, with the important qualification that that limit exists.  But as you have calculated, the partial derivative $f_x$ everywhere except $0$ is given by
$$
2 \cos \theta \sin^3 \theta
$$
Now, the problem is where you take the limit as $\rho \to 0$.  In fact, you should not be taking the limit in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but rather you need to take the limit **along the line $\boldsymbol{y=0}$**.  This is because the definition of the partial derivative is taken with the other variables held constant, so when computing $f_x$ at $(0,0)$, $y$ is held fixed at $0$.  So what am I getting at?  Well, you should be taking $\rho \to 0$, **with $\boldsymbol{\theta = 0 \textbf{ or } \pi}$** at the same time.  Thus you have
$$
f_x(0,0) = \lim_{\rho \to 0}_{\theta = 0, \pi} 2 \cos \theta \sin^3 \theta = 0.
$$
Similarly, you can compute the partial derivative $f_y$ by taking the limit with $\theta = \pm \pi/2$, and with the important qualification that this limit exists.
\begin{align*}
f_y(0,0)
&= \lim_{\rho \to 0}_{\theta = \pm \pi/2} 
\frac{x^4-x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \\
&= \lim_{\rho \to 0}_{\theta = \pm \pi/2} 
\frac{\rho^4 \cos^2 \theta (\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta)}{\rho^4} \\
&= \lim_{\rho \to 0}_{\theta = \pm \pi/2} 
\cos^2 \theta \cos (2\theta) = 0. \\
\end{align*}

In summary,

1. The standard rules of differentiation do work (in some sense) for partial derivatives, because a partial derivative is just a derivative with some variable held constant.
2. If the limit as $h$ goes to $0$ of $f_x(x + h, y)$ exists, then the partial derivative $f_x(x,y)$ exists and is equal to the limit.  Similarly for $f_y$.
3. (This is the important thing I think you were missing) **The partial derivative $f_x$ is taken with $y$ held constant, and the partial derivative $f_y$ is taken with $x$ held constant**.  In particular, these are not really limits taken in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but rather limits as only one variable goes to $0$.  And when you switch to polar coordinates and want to compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$, that means the angle is taken to have just two fixed possibilities as $\rho \to 0$.

Comment: If a function is differentiable at a point, then both partial derivatives exist there. Having both partial derivatives at a point does not guarantee that a function is differentiable
there.

Comment: @FlybyNight That is true.

Comment: @FlybyNight Which part of my post is that an objection to?

Comment: @GitGud Didn't see you had edited your comment.  Let's delete the comments; I revised the answer a bit to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: I found the other answer more clear and complete but I appreciate the using of polar coordinates you showed to me which was one the doubts of my question not treated in the previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

To work out $\mathrm{f}_x$ you need to use the limit definition:

$$\left.\frac{\partial\mathrm{f}}{\partial x}\right|_{x=y=0} = \lim_{h \to 0} \ \frac{\mathrm{f}(h,0) - \mathrm{f}(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\ \frac{0-0}{h} = 0$$

To find the partial derivative $\mathrm{f}_y(0,0)$ you need to find the limit

$$\left.\frac{\partial\mathrm{f}}{\partial y}\right|_{x=y=0} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathrm{f}(0,h)-\mathrm{f}(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \ \frac{0-0}{h} = 0$$

To see if $\mathrm{f}$ is differentiable at $x=y=0$ then we need to show that $z=\mathrm{f}(x,y)$ is well approximated by a plane close to $x=y=0$. Since $\mathrm{f}(0,0)=\mathrm{f}_x(0,0) = \mathrm{f}_y(0,0) = 0$ then the only candidate for this plane is $z=0$. To see if $z=\mathrm{f}(x,y)$ is approximated by the plane $z=0$ we need to show that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\mathrm{f}(x,y)-(0x+0y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$$

This is the ideal time to use polar coordinates: $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. We need to show

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \ \frac{\mathrm{f}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)-(0x+0y)}{\sqrt{r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta}} = 0$$

We can simplify this quite considerably:

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \ \frac{\mathrm{f}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)}{r} = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{r} = \cos^2\theta\sin\theta$$

This limit depends on $\theta$, which means it is not unique. Since the limit is not well-defined, it follows that $\mathrm{f}$ is not differentiable at $x=y=0$. I've attached a picture below which shows the surface $z=\mathrm{f}(x,y)$ and the plane $z=0$. Notice what bad of a job the plane does at being tangent to the surface at the origin. The blue line is the line $z=\mathrm{f}(0,y)$, the green line is $z=\mathrm{f}(x,0)$ and the red line is $z=\mathrm{f}(t,t)$.

[image]

Comment: @FlybyNight Why is it you say the standard rules of differentiation are not allowed?  A partial derivative is just a standard derivative with some variables held constant.  So the standard rules should work perfectly fine.  I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Good answer, though (+1).

Comment: @Goos The usual rules, e.g. chain rule, product rule and quotient rule only work when we know that the function is differentiable. I suppose there might be some pathological examples where they still hold. But, in general, you can't use the standard rules of differentiation until you're sure that the function is differentiable.

Comment: With regards to the directional derivative in the direction $(1,1)$, I agree it equals $1/2$.  **However,** you normally take the directional derivative in the direction of a vector of norm 1, so you would take it in the direction $(1 / \sqrt{2}, 1 / \sqrt{2})$.  Which means the answer is $ 1 / (2 \sqrt{2})$.

Comment: @FlybyNight You can still use the quotient rule like the OP did.  The partial derivative $f_x(0,0)$ is just the derivative at $0$ of the function $f$ restricted to the domain where $y = 0$.  So you can use the quotient rule just like you use it in one variable, as long as you keep in mind that $y$ is a constant (and in fact $y$ in this case is $0$).

Comment: @FlybyNight I agree, however, that doing the limit directly $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h}$ is a better approach.

Answer (score -1):

I know it has been past two years when this question was asked, but I study that example and I think I can show you some new idea that hasn't been shown so future reader can learn something.

 The main idea is to use Squeeze theorem and AG inequality.
$$\frac{x+y}{2}>=\sqrt{xy}$$
$$\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{4}>=xy$$
$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{1}>=2xy$$
$$\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}>=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{xy*|x|}{x^2+y^2}>=\frac{1}{2}*|x|$$
So we can squeeze our limit and use absolute of that:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow 0,0}|\frac{x^2*y}{x^2+y^2}|$$
$$0=<|\frac{x^2*y}{x^2+y^2}|<=\frac{1}{2}*|x|$$
SO by the squeeze theorem this limit is equal to zero and function is continous at $(0,0).$